# Passing void as out parameter

Tags: c#

Is there a way to ignore an out parameter? I.e.

```
bool myIntIsValid = int.TryParse(stringValue, void);
```

or

```
bool myIntIsValid = int.TryParse(stringValue, out new int());
```

Comment: use `int.Parse(stringValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to pass it a variable, but you're free to ignore it afterwards.